# How to sshpass multihop?

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

I'm trying to do a double sshpass hop like this:

`sshpass -p"password1" ssh user1@host1 -p2200` -> *then* -> `sshpass -p"password2" ssh user2@host2`

I've tried with

`sshpass -p"password1" ssh user1@host1 -p2200 -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p host2" user2@host2`

But I get:

> Host key verification failed.

My idea is to open a terminal and execute several commands in a somewhat automated manner without having to intervene the NATs port forwarding in my path.

The ultimate goal is to modify my ssh config to make several aliases like shown here http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html and then just log into subnet hosts like:

`ssh host1` to login to host1

`ssh host2` to login to host2 (which is inside the network of host1)

What is the correct way to do it?

**EDIT**: *I'm aware of public keys, but I want to know how to do it this way.*

Comment: If you want to automate this, the right thing to do is authenticate with keys, not passwords.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware.